# C++/CLI .NET Dependencies?

Tags: .net, dependencies, c++-cli, .net-assembly

I've recently taken up VC++.
In C#, I had a line like this:

```
byte[] rn = File.ReadAllBytes("...");
Assembly.Load(rn);
```

But I wanted to use a native language to do the same thing. Naturally I went with C++.

Now, I notice on MSDN I can call Assembly.Load(byte[]) from the System.Reflection namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx

But wouldn't this add .NET dependencies? Therefor defeating the purpose of me using C++ (or C++/CLI, I'm unsure of the difference) over C#?

Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: C++-CLI aleady uses the .NET framework So if you want to use the .NET framework and garbage collection you can use C++-CLI (or the newer C++-CX) instead. Of course, the code won't be portable to anything outside the Windows environment.

Comment: I'll be developing for Windows. So there would be no point in using C++/CLI for what I want to do, over using a language like C#? I'm just trying to avoid dependencies.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. You need to clarify your ideas a bit. What do you _really_ need to do? C++/CLI is a .NET language, just like C# or VB.NET. C++ is not a .NET language, but if you use it, don't use Microsoft's documentation, which mixes everything up.

Comment: Ok, so C++/CLI, C#, and VB.NET are all in the same .NET boat.
I just want to accomplish what I'm doing in my example code in native C++ (no .NET). But perhaps that's a different question altogether. Thanks for your help, I'm a bit mixed up right now. Silly that C++/CLI is different from C++. :/

Comment: @Joe What was "silly" was Microsoft's choice of "C++/CLI" (and, earlier, even worse: "Managed Extensions to C++") as a name for one of their .NET languages. C++ has a very well established meaning, despite Microsoft's efforts to introduce confusion.

Comment: Do you want to know how to read a whole file in one line in C++ or how to do reflection in C++?

Comment: Standard C++ does not support reflection. However, the Windows API supports loading DLLs and dynamically calling an exported function (see `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`). But you won't get anything like the extensive type information or on-the-fly code generation granted by .Net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeed pretty lost, you are not actually writing C++ code.  Using methods like File::ReadAllBytes() and Assembly::Load() is only possible when you write code in the C++/CLI language.  Which is one of the three .NET languages supported in Visual Studio, C++/CLI, VB.NET and C#.

C++/CLI is pretty special since the compiler also supports writing native C++ code and freely mixing it with .NET code.  You can use the standard C++ library and as long as you keep your code compliant with the C++03 language standard, the compiler will translate your code to IL without a complaint.  Plus you'll get access to all the .NET Framework classes, like File and Assembly.

The result however does *not* resemble anything like what you'd get from a pure C++ compiler.  You'll get a .NET assembly, the exact same kind of animal you'd get when you write your code in C#.  It gets just-in-time compiled at runtime by the jitter, even your pure C++ code gets that treatment.

If you want to create a real C++ program then you'll have to get started with another project template.  Avoid the CLR node, pick the Win32 node instead to pick your project template.  Beware of the culture shock you'll experience, nothing you've learned to rely on in the .NET Framework will be available in a pure C++ project.  No equivalent of the File class, you'll need to use `<iostream>`.  And certainly no Assembly class, there is no equivalent for that in native code.  LoadLibrary() + GetProcAddress() are probably the closest match, very hard to use.  Be prepared to dispose all assumptions about how you expected it to work and find yourself a good C++ book with exercises to survive.

If you are doing this to avoid dependencies then do beware that it isn't unlikely that you'll end up with the exact opposite problem.  A non-trivial C++ project that uses DLLs will make you end up with dependencies on the C runtime DLLs.  Which *must* be deployed on the user's machine by you, they don't come preinstalled on Windows, like .NET.

Comment: Thank you, it all seems like quite a mess, but this defiantly helps. Yes I think I had a Native Win32 project going, but there was an option to switch it to C++/CLI so I could use that class.